# How well do magnets work in zero kelvin?

Tags: magnetic-fields, cryogenics

I have read about zero-point energy, this means - alongside Heisenberg's uncertainty principle - that electrons can never be completely motionless. Therefore, since magnet strength is proportional to temperature, how strong would such a supercooled magnet be? Theoretically, would it even work? Or does it undergo a phase transition from magnetic to non-magnetic?

Furthermore, I found the extract:

"at higher magnetic fields and very low temperatures, they (magnetic spins) appear to become entangled with conduction electrons to create quasi-particles that behave like very heavy electrons. "

What is the effect of such particles to the magnetic properties of the material?

Sorry if I am too vague or asked too many questions :/, just really intrigued.